# can not collect legend with plot_layout() from patchwork package in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, patchwork

Just as the title.
I have a plot.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')
```

When I use `+` to combine plots, I can collect legend.

```
p + p + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

When I use `|` to combine plots, I can NOT collect legend.

```
p | p + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

I do not why.

What is the difference between `|` and `+`, and When use `|`, when use `+`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of how the nesting level is calculated according to operator precedence.

```r
p + p + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

is interpreted as

```
((p + p) + plot_layout(guides = 'collect'))
```

Whereas

```r
p | p + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

is interpreted as

```r
p | (p + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

Whereas you want

```r
(p | p) + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image]

Comment: @ Allan. Thanks.  I still have a question: What is the difference between | and +, and When use |, when use +.